# Post Data using Restkit

Tags: iphone, ios, ipod, ipod-touch

Here is my code for posting data:

```
DBMessage * message = [DBMessage object];

message.title = tokenFieldView.subjectField.text;
message.body = messageView.text;
message.username = [DBUser currentUser].username;

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:message delegate:self];
```

My code crashes at last line where delegate is set, at crash no messages displayed.

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint and enable logging in RestKit to see what's going on.

Comment: I have used restkit log,even my delegate method didFailWithError not called

Comment: i  first define a rout for  where  need to creat new post after that code is in post

Comment: when it reaches                                       [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:message delegate:self];      this line it crashes as sigabart